# Attach debugger to an already running Xamarin.Android process

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working with a proprietary device running Android 8.1, which is rooted. The app I'm developing needs to interact with some system libraries and specific hardware and it needs to be installed as a system app to be functioning.

I need to copy the APK manually along with the native .so libraries for the app to work as a system app, but it does work. I need a way to debug it.

I can't just start the app in debug mode as it will try to deploy the app as an user app, which will fail due to a package name conflict. Is there any way to attach the debugger to an already running app from Visual Studio? I found some information about this but looks like that none of the options mentioned are present in the latest 2022 Community Edition anymore.

I also tried Jetbrains Rider which does have this functionality. It detects the process but won't attach, I have a pending issue about this.

Any other ways to do this?